# Center a child based on the height of the parent in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to reliaze a display like the following where the arrows are placed in the middle based on the height of the main container.

[image: Display Im trying to realize]

Apart the fact that Im unable to place the arrows in the middle, I can not also increase the height of the icon (from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

However this is what I have realized so far:

[image: What I have done]

```css
.container {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Text over image*/
h2.header {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 padding: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
 font-family: FeaturedItem;
}
.item {
    position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

.item img {
   display: block;
   max-width:100%;
}

.item .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    color:white;
}

/*Carousel Nav Buttons*/

.carousel-nav-left{
 font-size: 30px;
 margin-left: -40px;
 top: 50%;
}

.carousel-nav-right{
 font-size: 30px;
 margin-right: -40px;
 top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>owlcarousel</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.carousel.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
 
    <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="carousel">
   
    <div class="item">
     <img src="images/2.jpg"  alt="" />
     
     <div class="overlay">
      <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
     <img src="images/1.jpg"  alt="" />
     
     <div class="overlay">
      <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
     <img src="images/3.jpg"  alt="" />
     
     <div class="overlay">
      <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
     <img src="images/4.jpg"  alt="" />
     
     <div class="overlay">
      <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
     <img src="images/5.jpg"  alt="" />
     
     <div class="overlay">
      <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
     <img src="images/6.jpg"  alt="" />
     
     <div class="overlay">
      <h2 class="header">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>
     </div>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   (function($){
 
    $('.carousel').owlCarousel({
     items: 3,
     loop:true,
     margin:10,
     nav:true,
     navText: ["<span class='carousel-nav-left'><i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i></span>","<span class='carousel-nav-right'><i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i></span>"],
     dots: true,
     responsive:{
      0:{
       items:1
      },
      430:{
       items:2
      },
      800:{
       items:3
      },
      1400:{
       items:4
      },
      1800:{
       items:6
      },
      2400:{
       items:7
      },
      3000:{
       items:9
      }
     }
    })
    
   })(jQuery);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can set a fixed height on the arrows you can use position absolute and a margin trick to do the following;

**Note** - This *may* also require a fixed height on `.container`.

```
.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-nav-left{
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin: auto 0;
    margin-left: -40px;
}

.carousel-nav-right{
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin: auto 0;
    margin-right: -40px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is now working but Iam still unable to increase the height of the span where my icons are located. Kindly help me solve this issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not 100% sure what you mean.

Comment: Im still unable to increase the height of the prev/next buttons

Comment: If you're using font awesome, then it's font size

Answer (score 1):

If you can use flexbox ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) is pretty good these days), this should be easy even if the height of the arrow is not known:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ffc;
}

.arrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow">
    <span class="button">&lt;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <span class="button">&gt;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is now working but Iam still unable to increase the height of the span where my icons are located. Kindly help me solve this issue.

Comment: You can just set a height on the span.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're missing a 'position' element in the css for you nav elements (.carousel-nav-right and carousel-nav-left). Also, using he Chrome browser you can right click on your nav elements click 'inspect element' and view the css path to make sure you've got the correct css selectors. There are potentially a lot of nested elements you may need to account for.